# Confusion with the definition of the C1 norm on the space of 1-forms

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, symplectic-geometry

I am looking for the definition of the $C^1$ norm of a differential 1-form. I came across this while reading Theorem 10.1.1 from McDuff-Salamon's Symplectic Topology book. I am really stuck at this, and my guess so far has produced this, for a differential 1-form $\sigma$, and a given Riemannian metric $g$ on the symplectic manifold $M$,
$$||\sigma||_{C^1}:= \inf_{x\in M} \sup_{||v||=1}|\sigma(v)|$$
where I am taking the infimum of the pointwise operator norms.

It would be really helpful if someone could confirm if this is correct, and provide with the correct definition of not.

I would also be interested to know if there are general formulas to define the $C^k$ norm of a differential $l$-form. Thanks.

Comment: I think the $C^1$ norm should refer to $\|\sigma\|_p = \sup_{\|v\|=1} |\sigma(v)| + \sup_{\|v\|=\|w\|=1} |\mathrm{d}\sigma(u,v)|$, and $\|\sigma\| = \sup_p \|\sigma\|_p$, although I'm not sure. But $C^1$ usually implies the use of the differential.

Comment: @Didier, the exterior derivative isn’t enough. Your answer is correct if you replace the $d$ by $\nabla$.

Comment: @Kajelad, your norm is commonly called a Sobolev $W^{2,1}$ norm and is weaker than a $C^1$ norm.

Comment: @Deane, it would be really helpful if you could provide a reference for this, I was not able to find this definition anywhere.

Comment: You can try looking at Hebey's book, Sobolev Spaces on Riemannian Manifolds, which looks at $L^p$ Sobolev spaces for $p \ge 1$. Most of what's in Chapters 1 and 2 extend to $p = \infty$. Also, if you already understand how $C^k$ norms for functions work, it's relatively straightforward to figure out how to extend the definitions and theorems to vector-valued functions and then to tensor fields.